# PyQt6 / finplot - Compatability Issue? (problem isolated to small runnable code)

Tags: python, pyqtgraph, pyqt6

My head is spinning from trying to get finplot to create an embedded graph for days with no luck.  I decided to restart small.

The code that I included works as-is.  However, if I change the import to PyQt6 from PyQt5, it stops working.

The application that I am trying to integrate this into is all done in PyQt6.  finplot works and displays externally in my PyQt6 attempts, but I cannot use fplt.create_plot_widget while passing self.window() with PyQt6, it seems.

Honestly, I keep running into trouble any time i try to use pyqtgraph.  I sidetracked to do something clever with mplfinance, but I'm back to where i was 6 months ago with trying to get anything graph and Qt related to show up in a layout nicely with the other widgets :/

Any help is appreciated.  Thank you.

```
import sys
import finplot as fplt
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import *
import yfinance

class App(QMainWindow):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.title = 'PyQt5 - QTabWidget'
        self.left = 0
        self.top = 0
        self.width = 600
        self.height = 400
        self.setWindowTitle(self.title)
        self.setGeometry(self.left, self.top, self.width, self.height)
        self.menu = self.menuBar()

        self.widget = MyGraphWidget(self)
        self.setCentralWidget(self.widget)

        fplt.show(qt_exec=False)
        self.show()

class MyGraphWidget(QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent):
        super(QWidget, self).__init__(parent)
        self.layout = QVBoxLayout(self)

        self.resize(600, 400)
        self.label = QLabel("AAPL")
        self.df = yfinance.download('AAPL')
        self.fplt_widget1, self.fplt_widget2 = fplt.create_plot_widget(self.window(), rows=2)
        fplt.candlestick_ochl(self.df[['Open', 'Close', 'High', 'Low']])

        self.layout.addWidget(self.label)
        self.window().axs = [self.fplt_widget1]
        self.layout.addWidget(self.fplt_widget1.ax_widget)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    ex = App()

    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

Comment: finplot just moved over to using pyqt6. Let me know if there are lingering problems.

Answer (score 1):

This is not an issue with `pyqtgraph`. That project currently supports PyQt6/PySide6.

However, looking at `finplot` project's `setup.py` [here](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/blob/master/setup.py), it looks like it is currently on PyQt5 (evidenced by the configuration line `install_requires=['pandas', 'PyQt5', 'pyqtgraph>=0.11.1'],`). The migration to PyQt6 would have to start there. There is some visible mention of hints toward PyQt6 in the project's issues [here](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/issues/139#issuecomment-796287496) and [here](https://github.com/highfestiva/finplot/issues/159#issuecomment-821762440).

As of today, it appears that your options are:

1. Submit an issue to `finplot`'s maintainer to request support for PyQt6.
2. Fork `finplot`, do the migration work yourself and submit a PR back.
3. Keep using `finplot` with PyQt5.